# AnimateWindow win32 Api

Tags: windows, winapi, desktop, system-tray

I have an application which has a notification area. Whenever I get a notification, I call the

```
::AnimateWindow(m_hWnd,duration,flags)
```

When the application window is visible or minimized, the notification works fine. When I close the application, it runs in the system tray. During this time, if a notification occurs, it takes the screen focus. So if I am on some other application, I lose focus on that one and have to click on the other app to get back the focus. Why is the AnimateWindow behaving differently depending upon whether the window is open or closed. Is there a way to tell the OS to stop the focus on the notification?

Update: I think the description was not clear. The animate window is used to show the notification in the system tray. This is not for the main app window.

Comment: What are you passing for `flags`? `AW_ACTIVATE` will activate the window.

Comment: I am not using `AW_ACTIVATE` at all. The flags are only for slide animation. Also why would the behavior be different when I am using the same code both the times. Is it the expected behavior of windows?

Comment: I don't know. But if your window is hidden the animation isn't going to be visible anyway, so why not just test for this condition and call `ShowWindow` instead?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys, my investigation was incomplete. Actually I was using CEF createBrowser() to create a notification. Apparently that was stealing the focus.